# create s3 objects based on s3 files

Tags: regex, shell, amazon-s3

I'm new AWS. I have s3 files in bucket like below. I want to create directory based on the filename and copy the respective file to s3 directory in shell script.
**Example**

```
aws s3 ls s3://dev-ft-raw/dest/20190516/

DEST_PROD.OFFER-20190516.csv
DEST_PROD.GUARANTEE-20190516.csv
```

**OUTPUT**

```
s3://dev-ft-raw/dest/output/OFFER/DEST_PROD.OFFER-20190516.csv

s3://dev-ft-raw/dest/output/GUARANTEE/DEST_PROD.GUARANTEE-20190516.csv
```

Comment: Pls show shell script

Comment: What have you tried? What difficulties have you encountered? What is your actual question?

Comment: @RyanNghiem I tried following way                                                       
O=$(aws s3 ls s3://sdx-ft-raw/destimo/20190516/ |awk -F"." '{print $2}' | awk -F"-" '{print $1}');
while true ; do
    C=$(aws s3 cp s3://sdx-ft-raw/destimo/20190516/ s3://sdx-ft-raw/destimo/ANY/$O/);
done